# Connecting Client and server with JavaRMI

Tags: java, rmi

I wrote an application in Java RMI and the server-side part is in a machine and the client-side is in another one. Well, I can't connect the client to the server. I am trying 
to pass the ip machine to the client, but it doesn't work. When the client and the server  are in the same machine and I pass to the client the 'localhost' everything works.
How can I make the client find the server?

Let's suppose the server ip is xxx and the aplication is running is the yyy door, so
to connect the client to the server I do: java Client xxx:yyy

```
public class Client {

  public static void main(String [] args){

  String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
  try {

     Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);

     Estagios stub = (Estagios) registry.lookup("Estagios");

   }
  ....
 }
```

thaks.

Comment: A good tutorial is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_2AOJb-_NY

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @Makky The tutorial isn't bad, a few mistakes. The `main()` method can be in the server class itself. The result of `Registry.createRegistry()` must be stored in a static variable, otherwise it is liable to GC, and the server object is then liable to DGC and GC. You don't need `Constant:`  the lookup name is best as the name of the remote interface, e.g. RemoteInterface.class.getName(); and you should use Registry.REGISTRY_PORT rather than 222. You don't have to extend `UnicastRemoteObject.` You should call `super(0)` or use zero as the port number when exporting, to avoid stub generation.